# Auto-trigger HTML Event Handler for Meta Tags

Tags: html

I basically want a `<meta>` tag to immediately trigger a javascript event, but onload= does not seem to work.

My next attempt involved autofocus/onfocus, but that didn't work either.

Are there any event handlers that can be used with meta tags to do what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: More info.

I am a web application pentester. I've found a persistent XSS in a client's webpage, and would like to make a working PoC for them to show them the danger. The tag looks as the following example:

<meta content="INJECTIONgarbage characters">

> is sanitized, so breaking out of the meta tag is out of the option. " is not sanitized, which is the vulnerability.

I can demonstrate to them danger via something like:

0"http-equiv=refresh b="

Which refreshes the page constantly, which looks like more of a cute parlor trick than an actual threat vector.

Due to a 30-character limitation, I am not able to meaningfully redirect to an external site. The best I could do is 5-characters.

If onload worked, I could do something like:

"onload=alert() b="

(Meta tag would look like): <meta content onload=alert() b="garbage">

This would allow me to demonstrate a more serious threat vector, because I could include arbitrary JS at that point to buy myself more space (and thus, provide a hook for BeEF).

I'm still going to present it to them even if I can't include arbitrary JS, but I feel like my report is more likely to be considered unimportant if I can't even show JS execution, and this is a *persistent* XSS, so I want it to be taken seriously.

Comment: Please post an extract of your code. It may be that `onload` would work correctly for what you are trying to achieve, however you may be using the incorrect syntax - by posting your code, SO users have the opportunity to see what you are working with, what you have tried and a better understanding of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Will edit the OP with more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use the onload trigger with a meta tag.

The tags compatible with the onload function include the [following](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp):

```
<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```